# Ansible regex_search module

Tags: ansible, regex

Can anyone please help me to explain this code in ansible regex_search module:

```
- set_fact:
    regex: "{{ '/opt/conf/path.txt' | regex_search('/?(.*)', '\\1') }}'
```

- What "\\1" means in this code.
- What is the function of each special letter in '/?(.*)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually more of a regex-question, not ansible. Apart from that, all information you are looking for is in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and [ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions).

- `\\1` will return the first matching group
- `/?(.*)` has several parts

  - `/?` will match a `/` if it is there, or nothing if it isn't. The `?` means "optional".
  - Everything in brackets `()` is a matching-group. You can have multiple to get different parts of your match, but here it is only one.
  - `.*` matches any string composed of any character except new-lines of any length, as `.` matches any character (except newline) and `*` means, 0 or more characters.

Check the documentation linked above, they explain all this in detail.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer, now I got it.